# What warrants "Hot Network Questions"

Tags: discussion

Just curious as to what makes a question a "Hot Network Question". Is it view count, votes or a combination of both?

Comment: This would be better as a question on MSO - in fact, [there is one already there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page/61343#61343 is the official MSE answer.

Comment: Any question I ask, obvs

Comment: This should be tagged as [tag:hot-network-questions]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [David Fullerton's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/262849) on another stack

### **[How do the "arbitrary hotness points" work on the new Stack Exchange home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page/61343#61343)**

> Basically what's documented here:
>
> [What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)
>
> We have a few tweaks:
>
> - Succeeding questions from the same site are penalized by increasing amounts.  So, the first question from SO in the list gets multiplied
>     by 1.0, the second by 0.98, the third by 0.96, etc)
> - We make a per-site traffic adjustment so SO does not dominate the entire list
> - The benefit of many answers is capped at 10
> - We only degrade based on question age, and not the last update date on a question, so questions don't pop back up to the top every time
>     they're edited
> - Views are not counted towards the score
>
> The core of the formula (without the site-based degrading or traffic
>   scaling) is:
>
> ```
>  (MIN(AnswerCount, 10) * QScore) / 5 + AnswerScore
> ```
>
> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------
> ```
>
> ```
>           MAX(QAgeInHours + 1, 6) ^  1.4
> ```